# jQuery .data() returning value AND undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
// jQuery:
$('.slidebutton').click(function(event) {
  var slide = $(this).data('slide');
  slide = "#slide-"+slide;
  alert(slide);
});
```

```html
<!-- HTML: -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-sixth"><a data-slide="1" class="slidebutton">RECRUITING</a></div>
<div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="2" class="slidebutton">ONBOARDING</a></div>
<div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="3" class="slidebutton">PERFORMANCE</a></div>
<div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="4" class="slidebutton">LEARNING</a></div>
<div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="5" class="slidebutton">HRMS</a></div>
<div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="6" class="slidebutton">TALENT APPS</a></div>
```

The result is two alerts.  The first is right, but the second is always #slide-undefined

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The click event is bubbling up to the parent `<div>`, which also has the `slidebutton` class. There are two possible solutions:

1. Prevent the event from bubbling:

   ```
   $('.slidebutton').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation(); // http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/
     var slide = $(this).data('slide');
     slide = "#slide-"+slide;
     alert(slide);
   });
   ```

   ```js
       $('.slidebutton').click(function(event){
         event.stopPropagation(); // http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/
         var slide = $(this).data('slide');
         slide = "#slide-"+slide;
         alert(slide);
       });
   ```

   ```html
       <!-- HTML: -->
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="one-sixth"><a data-slide="1" class="slidebutton">RECRUITING</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="2" class="slidebutton">ONBOARDING</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="3" class="slidebutton">PERFORMANCE</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="4" class="slidebutton">LEARNING</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="5" class="slidebutton">HRMS</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="6" class="slidebutton">TALENT APPS</a></div>
   ```
2. Only attach the event listener to each child `<a>`:

   ```
   $('a.slidebutton').click(function(){ // a.slidebutton
     var slide = $(this).data('slide');
     slide = "#slide-"+slide;
     alert(slide);
   });
   ```

   ```js
       $('a.slidebutton').click(function(){ // a.slidebutton
         var slide = $(this).data('slide');
         slide = "#slide-"+slide;
         alert(slide);
       });
   ```

   ```html
       <!-- HTML: -->
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <div class="one-sixth"><a data-slide="1" class="slidebutton">RECRUITING</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="2" class="slidebutton">ONBOARDING</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="3" class="slidebutton">PERFORMANCE</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="4" class="slidebutton">LEARNING</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="5" class="slidebutton">HRMS</a></div>
       <div class="one-sixth slidebutton"><a data-slide="6" class="slidebutton">TALENT APPS</a></div>
   ```